# Google Apps Script Error: You do not have permission to call newTrigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have this Google apps script in my spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if (row == 1) {
    return;
  }
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  email = email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@'));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 2).setValue(email);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 3).setValue(new Date());
}

function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

Which causes this error:

`Google Apps Script: You do not have permission to call newTrigger`

Apparently this script has run correctly for some time and now it doesn't. I imagine some change occurred in the API that causes this?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a trigger outside the onOpen function else it will run every time you load the Google Sheet in your browser.